# Watson Visual Recognition Custom Classifiers in Node Red with Base64 Encoded Images

Tags: image, zip, node-red, watson, visual-recognition

I am currently working on an use case where I want to show how simple it is to train Watson Visual Recognition.

The images I get are base64 encoded and I know that there is an base64 node to create a binary buffer of the string/image.

Visual Recognition wants at least 20 images to be ready for classification. So it needs two times 10 images in a zip-folder (binary buffer of the zip folder). Now I have the problem when I use the ZIP node in Node-Red that it only can create a ZIP buffer of image buffers and visual recognition wants a zip buffer of images and not of image buffers.

I don't know how to custom the classifiers when I only have access to the base64 string of the images, because they get uploaded with Skype and I can't get them in png or jpg format.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  You should have a look at creating a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as we'll be more likely to be able to help with that.

Comment: I tried the Zip node that creates a zip buffer out of image buffers and I tried to upload the image buffers to dropbox and download them as zip but they did not appear as jpg or png in dropbox.